# Equation in ordinal numbers

Tags: ordinals

How to find two ordinals $\alpha,\beta:$
$$
\omega^3+4\omega^2+\omega\cdot 5+1= (\omega+3)\alpha+\beta?
$$
Any hint would be much appreciated

Comment: Try $\alpha=0$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen and if $\alpha$ is non-zero?

Comment: @GregoryG: For $\alpha=1$, and in fact, any value below $\omega^2$, you get the same result as with $\alpha=0$ (although less trivially so). You might want to require $\alpha$ to have the largest possible value (if such thing is possible).

Comment: I guess you want the solution with $\beta\lt\omega+3$.

Comment: Division algorithm: given ordinals $\gamma,\delta$ with $\delta\gt0$, we can uniquely write $\gamma=\delta\alpha+\beta$ with $\beta\lt\delta$.

Comment: By the way, is $4\omega^2$ a typo for $\omega^2\cdot4$? If not, you may as well simplify it, since $4\omega^2=\omega^2$.

Comment: The answer is $\beta=\omega+1$ and $\alpha=\omega^2+\omega+4$ or maybe $\alpha=\omega^2+\omega4+4$ depending on what you meant by that funny-looking $4\omega^2$.

Comment: @bof thank you for your incredible comments! Yes $4\omega$ I just wanted to be on the safe side (I figured out this simplification, but since I'm a total newbie I wanted to be sure).